# watch changes and update formatted view with date object

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'm trying to do a navigation through days. So i need two buttons "previous", and "next day" to change formatted date.

```
[ <<PREV ]    DD-MM-YYY (weekday)   [ NEXT >> ]
```

And i have a problem because my day variable is an Date object. I tried computed, methods, and watchers but no simple solution.

Project working good with additional variables but there must be a better way to do this simple component.

Here is what i have:

```js
let app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    day: new Date(),
    dayFormated: "not set",
    number: 1
  },
  computed: {
    dateFormated: function() {
      // computed values are cached 
      return this.showFormatedDate(this.day);
    }
  },
  watch: {
    day: {
      handler: function(val, oldVal) {
        // this is not working at all
        console("day changed");
        this.dayFormated = this.showFormatedDate(this.day);
      },
      deep: true
    },
    number: function(val) {
      // this updates dayFormated but this can't be best solution
      // and dayFormated is not set at the begining
      // this.dayFormated = this.showFormatedDate(this.day);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    previous: function() {
      console.log("prev");
      // when next line commented method showFormatedDate is not updating
      this.number--; 
      this.day.setDate(this.day.getDate() - 1);
    },
    next: function() {
      console.log("next");
      // when next line commented method showFormatedDate is not updating
      this.number++;
      this.day.setDate(this.day.getDate() + 1);
    },
    showFormatedDate: function(date) {
      let formated = date.toLocaleDateString(["pl-PL"], {
        day: "2-digit",
        month: "2-digit",
        year: "numeric"
      });
      formated +=
        " (" + date.toLocaleDateString(["pl-PL"], { weekday: "long" }) + ")";
      return formated;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  padding-top: 2rem;
}

.column {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.2/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app" class="container">  
  
  <h1 class="subtitle has-centered-text">number: {{number}}</h1>
  
  <div class="columns">
    
      <div class="column">
        <button class="button is-large is-fullwidth" @click="previous">PREV</button>    
      </div> 
    
      <div class="column">data:<br>{{day}}</div>
      <div class="column">computed:<br>{{dateFormated}}</div>
      <div class="column">method:<br>{{showFormatedDate(day)}}</div>
      <div class="column">watch:<br>{{dayFormated}}</div>
    
      <div class="column">
        <button class="button is-large is-fullwidth" @click="next">NEXT</button>  
      </div>  
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work, beucase Vue doesn't watch on mutations inside objects ([Vue Reactivity in Depth: Change Detection Caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats)).

These 2 lines mutate the object `day`, but Vue doesn't see the changes, because the reference to the object (`this.day`) stays the same:

```
this.day.setDate(this.day.getDate() - 1);
this.day.setDate(this.day.getDate() + 1);
```

If you change that to assigning a new object it works, because now the reference to `this.day` has changed and Vue notices the changed value:

```
this.day = new Date(this.day.setDate(this.day.getDate() - 1));
this.day = new Date(this.day.setDate(this.day.getDate() + 1));
```

Pen with corrected working code [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zyLqVa).

Comment: Thank you for your response. 
This project is educational, so that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually the first time I've worked with Vue.

I added [Moment](https://momentjs.com) to your deps because it makes it easy to format the date the way you want.

I think I've pared this down to a fairly simple solution. I did run into an issue where Vue wasn't reacting to the date change when I was storing the date as a moment object (even with `this.$set(this, 'date', this.date.add(1, 'day')` or adding a deep watcher), so I gave up on that approach and stored the date as a unix timestamp (epoch seconds) instead, which works fine:

```js
let app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    date: moment().startOf('day').unix()
  },
  methods: {
    dateString: function() {
      return moment.unix(this.date).format('DD-MM-YYYY (dddd)');
    },
    previous: function() {
      this.date = moment.unix(this.date).subtract(1, 'day').unix();
    },
    next: function() {
      this.date = moment.unix(this.date).add(1, 'day').unix();
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  padding-top: 2rem;
}

.column {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.2/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app" class="container">  
  <div class="columns">
      <div class="column">
        <button class="button is-large is-fullwidth" @click="previous">PREV</button>    
      </div> 
      <div class="column">{{ dateString() }}</div>
      <div class="column">
        <button class="button is-large is-fullwidth" @click="next">NEXT</button>  
      </div>  
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: Click on `Run code snipet` and then `Full Page` (over to the right) to see the demo